# Prove an estimation to approximate the $k$rd decimal place by Newton's method

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, newton-raphson

When I use Bisection method to find a solution $r$ of equation $f \in C^2[a,b]$, within tolerance $10^{-k}$ and approximate to the $k$rd decimal place.

For each step, assume that $x_n=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2} \in \mathbb Q^c$. I want to approximate $x_n$ to the $l-$rd decimal place $\overline{x_n}$ 
 ($l > k$).  I know that exit $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $$|\overline{x_n} - r| \leq 10^{-k } \text{ } \forall n \geq N.(1)$$
I tthink it will help calculate easier and guarantee the accuracy of approximation $\overline{x_n}$.

Prove (1)

Let $d_n=\frac{a_n-b_n}{2}$
$$|\overline{x_n} - r| \leq |\overline{x_n} - x_n | + |x_n -r| \leq \frac{1}{2}10^{-l}+\frac{d_n}{2}$$
clearly,
$$d_{n+1} \leq \frac{d_n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}10^{-l}\leq ... \leq \frac{d_1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2}10^{-l}. (2)$$
So that 
$$|\overline{x_n}-r|\leq \frac{d_1}{2^n}+10^{-l}$$
When $ n \longrightarrow \infty$ , $\frac{d_1}{2^n} \longrightarrow 0$, as $k >n$ , exit $N$ such that $$|\overline{x_n} - r| \leq 10^{-k } \text{ } \forall n \geq N.$$
When I use Newton's method, I also want to have (1),  but it's so hard for me to have the estimation like (2). I just know that
$$|x_n -r| \leq \frac{M}{2m}d_n^2$$
$M:=\max_{[a,b]}|f|, m:=\min_{[a,b]}|f'|$. (Assume this method is successful).

Help me, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that $d_n=\vert x_{n-1}-r\vert$. Then your estimate is *almost* true. $M$ has to be replaced by $M_2:=\max_{[a,b]}|f''|$ (see wikipedia on Newton iteration for example).

But this is not what you are looking for. But you get an explicit estimate $|x_n-r|$ by observing $f(r)=0$, $|f(x_n)|=|f(x_n)-f(r)|=|f'(\xi) (x_n-r)|\geq m |x_n-r|$ or $|x_n-r|\leq\frac{|f(x_n|}{m}$.

Comment: yeah, thank you! I've got this result by using the estimation $|x_n -r| \leq \frac{|f(x_n)|}{m}$. We have $|\overline x_n -r| \leq \frac{1}{2}10^{-l} +\frac{|f(x_n)|}{m}$. As $f(x_n) \longrightarrow 0 $, let $\epsilon = m\left(\frac{1}{2}10^{-k}-\frac{1}{2}10^{-l}\right) >0$. Then exist $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $|f(x_n)| <\epsilon$. So $|\overline x_n -r| < \frac{1}{2}10^{-k}, \forall n \geq N.$